# Composer and automated unit tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, automated-tests, composer-php

I am using composer in my own / company projects for deployment, etc. I already use php unit tests, but now I also would like to add automated unit testing whenever the project is installed or updated, i.e., I would like to execute phpunit on the composer pre-autoload-dump event.
See https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md

Depending on the success of the unit tests, I would like to either continue or stop the installation process of my package. So if a unit test fails, the version should not be installed.

How would you suggest in general to proceed on this intention?

My composer.json looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "Cravid/event",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"Cravid\\Event\\": "src/Gkm/Event"}
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {"Cravid\\Event\\": "tests/Gkm/Event"}
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "1.0.x-dev"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-autoload-dump": "phpunit"
    }
}
```

Git is the designated version control system.

Answer (score 3):

You intention probably will create a huge amount of hassle.

You say that you want to run tests PRIOR to installation - but when running something in the pre-autoload-dump event, something already has been installed, namely the version of the software you are about to test. What if that software fails the test? Then you are stuck with a partially installed piece of software that did not correctly dump it's autoloader.

Additionally, not dumping the autoloader means you cannot use your software. And you cannot test it. And if you run `composer install` on your development machine to grab a faulty copy for investigation, the autoloading will also stop.

I think it is not a good idea to use Composer for everything. Composer is a great tool to manage software dependencies. In order to do so, it offers several hooks to allow even strange software requirements to add a little bit here and there, but in general you shouldn't need these.

To create something like continuous integration or continuous delivery with automatic tests, you have to use something outside of Composer. I'd recommend using [Phing](http://phing.info) to define the tasks that need to be done for some steps, and probably an instance of [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/) to allow executing the jobs.

Comment: Thx, I was hoping to do kinda CI with composer, just for simplicity reasons. But in this circumstances this would probably the wrong approach. I will take a look at Phing.

Comment: Phing can be installed very easily with  `composer global require phing/phing:~2.6`. It is then available as `~/.composer/vendor/bin/phing`, and the path `~/.composer/vendor/bin` should be added to your PATH (note that `~` probably won't work, you have to use either absolute path or a variable like `$HOME` depending on the place you want to make this change).